# How to use HoC with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, high-order-component

I have an listing app where users can add items for multiple categories, when they want to add new record, there are 3 related screens with this particular feature. All of those screens have `<Header/>` component, so i thought HoC would be nice here so that i can reuse it across 3 screens.
However, i could not accomplish it.

Here is what i tried so far:

This is my HoC class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import Header from '../components/Header';

const NewAd = (WrappedComponent) => {
    class NewAdHoc extends Component {
        handleBackPress = () => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
            StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content', true);
        }
        render() {
            const {contentText, children} = this.props
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Header
                        headerText={'Yeni ilan ekle'}
                        onPress={this.handleBackPress}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.contentHeader}>{contentText}</Text>
                        <WrappedComponent/>
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }


    return NewAdHoc;
}
```

this is my screen:

```
class NewAdScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        const Content = () => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.flatListContainer}>
                    <ListViewItem />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            NewAdHoc(Content)
        )
    }
}
```

after that i am getting error

```
TypeError: (0 , _NewAdHoc.NewAdHoc) is not a function(…)
```

and i have no idea how can i fix it because this is my first time using hocs on a react-native app. I have looked why this error is popping and they suggest import components in this way:

```
import {NewAdHoc} from '../hocs/NewAdHoc';
```

but even this is not solved it.

any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: NewAdHoc is a component that is returned from HOC NewAd. I think you should export NewAd and use NewAd instead of NewAdHoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main purpose of a `HOC` is to encapsulate and reuse `stateful` logic across components.  Since you are just reusing some `jsx` and injecting nothing in `WrappedComponent` you should be using a regular component here:

```
const NewAd = ({ contentText, children }) => {

    handleBackPress = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
        StatusBar.setBarStyle('dark-content', true);
    }


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header
                headerText={'Yeni ilan ekle'}
                onPress={this.handleBackPress}
            />
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.contentHeader}>{contentText}</Text>
                {children}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

And use it like this

```
return(
    <>
         <NewAd>
            <Screen1 />
         </NewAd>
         <NewAd>
            <Screen2 />
         </NewAd>
         <NewAd>
            <Screen3 />
         </NewAd>
    </>
)
```